# $ N $ normal in a finite group $ G $, $ |N| = 5 $ and $ |G| $ odd. Why is $ N \subseteq Z(G) $?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Suppose that $ N $ is a normal subgroup of a finite group $ G $. If $ |N| = 5 $ and $ |G| $ is odd, why is $ N $ contained in $ Z(G) $, the center of $ G $?

I know how to do this when $ |N| = 2 $ and $ |G| $ is even, but am not sure what to do with this one. Sylow's theorems maybe?

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 6):

Hint: $G/C_{G}(N)$ is a subgroup of the automorphism group of $N$, and that is easy to determine.

Answer (score 1):

If $|G|$ is odd, then the conjugacy classes must be of odd size either. As $N$ is normal, it is union of conjugacy classes, one of which must be the singleton $\{e\}$. But $5=1+2+2$, $5=1+4$ and $5=1+1+1+2$ are ruled out, because of the opening sentence; and $5=1+1+3$ is ruled out because then $\left|N\cap Z(G)\right|=2$, contradicting Lagrange's theorem. So, we are left with $5=1+1+1+1+1$, namely $N\subseteq Z(G)$.