# If $H$ is a normal subgroup of group $G$ of odd order and $|H|=5$ . show that $H \subseteq Z(G)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

If $H$ is a normal subgroup of group $G$ of odd order and $|H|=5$ . show that $H \subseteq Z(G)$

**Attempt:** If $|H|=5$ and if $H$ is normal, then $H$ must be a normal cyclic subgroup.

$\implies H = \{e,a,a^2,a^3,a^4\}$ for some $a \in G$

Since, $H$ is normal, $\implies gH = Hg \implies g a^i = a^j g$

And now, we need to prove that $i=j$.

$G$ is of odd order and $|H|=5 \implies$ index of $H$ in $G = [G:H] = |G|/|H|=2m-1$  is odd

$\implies g^{2m-1} \in H~~\forall~ g \in H$

How do I proceed further? Help will be appreciated.

Thank you

**Attempt 2:** By the $N/C$ Theorem : Since $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G \implies N(H) =G.$

Now, $H$ is cyclic of order $5 \implies H \subseteq C(H)$ and $|Aut(H)|=1,2$ or $4$

**CASE $1$ :** $|Aut(H)|=1 \implies |G|=|C(H)| \implies C(H)=G$

**CASE $2$:** $|Aut(H)|=2 \implies C(H)$ is normal in $G ~~ i.e.~~ C(H) \vartriangleleft G$.

**CASE $3$:** $|Aut(H)|=4 \implies G/C(H) \approx Z_2 \bigoplus Z_2 $ or $~ G/C(H) \approx Z_4$

We need to show that $\forall h \in H,~~ hg~=~gh ~~\forall g \in G$. I am kind of stuck again. Help will be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/267980/n-normal-in-a-finite-group-g-n-5-and-g-odd-why-is-n-s

Comment: There's a theorem called the N/C theorem that would be extremely helpful here.

Comment: Comment, if you don't get Geoff Robinson's excellent hint (=the answer to the question this is a duplicate of). +1 for showing your ideas. The key is to know what kind of automorphisms $H$ has.

Comment: So, the $N/C$ theorem states that if $H$ be a subgroup of $G$, then if $N(H) = \{n \in G|~ n Hn^{-1} = H\}$ represents the normalizer and $C(H) =\{c \in G| ~ch=hc ~\forall ~h \in H\}$ represents the centralizer, then $N(H)/C(H) \approx$ subgroup of $Aut(H)$.

Now, since $H$ is a normal subgroup, $\implies N(H) = G$ and hence $G/C(H) \approx $ subgroup of $Aut (H)$.

$Aut(H)$ represents the set of isomomorphisms $\Psi : H \rightarrow H$

uhm, So, I am still trying to determine the subgroup of this isomomorphism and relate $C(H)$..

Comment: @VHP, +1 for showing your ideas clearly. Now, what's the automorphism group of a *cyclic* (obviously) group of order a prime ? Now, what's the order of $\;G/C_G(H)\;$ according to the data you have?

Comment: No @VHP: since any non-unit of $\;H\;$ is a generator of $\;H\;$ and any automorphism must send a generator to a generator, we **only** have four automorphisms...

Comment: Yeah, my bad. Since $\phi(5) =4$ we have $4$ automorphisms

Comment: A group of order $4$ can have subgroup of order $4$ or of $2$. Hence, $G/C_G(H) \approx S_{Aut(H)}$ where $|S_{Aut(H)}|=2$ or $4$

Comment: but, since $G$ is not cyclic, $|S_{Aut(H)}|=2$

Comment: Well, @VHP: if $\;G\;$ is cyclic or even merely abelian then the question's trivial as $\;Z(G)=G\;$ , and if it is not then *anyway* $\;\text{Aut}\,(H)\cong C_4=$ the cyclic group of order $\;4\;$ . Now, what are the order of all its proper *non-trivial* subgroups? And what's the order of $\;G/C_G(H)\;$ ? So ...

Comment: the order of all it's proper non trivial subgroup can be $2$ only. Then, if $|G/C(H)|=2 \implies C(H) = \{c ∈ G| ch=hc ∀ h ∈ H\} $ is a normal subgroup of $G$.Hence, $g C(H) = C(H) g$ or $gc_1 =c_2 g \implies g c_1 h = c_2 gh \implies (gh) c_1 = c_2 (gh) \forall g \in G , h \in H \implies C(H)$ is normal in $H$  
Am i coming closer? Thank you

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen and DonAntonio  ----- I found a proof extending my attempt. So, i thought of sharing : 

If $H$ is a normal subgroup of group $G$ of odd order and $|H|=5$ . show that $H \subseteq Z(G)$

Proof: firstly : $H$ is cyclic as $|H|=5 \implies H = \{e,a,a^2,a^3,a^4\}$ . Now. $H$ is normal $\implies gH = Hg \implies ga^i = a^jg ...(1)$. Now, we need to prove that $i=j. (1) \implies ga^ig^{-1} = a^j$. But, since, $H$ is cyclic,it is abelian and $Z(H)=H ....(2)$. Since,$H/Z(H) \approx Inn(H)...(3)$ From $(2),(3)$, $Inn(H)$ must be the trivial mapping.Hence,$a^i =a^j, i=j$.

Comment: will this work?