# Show that the Sylow $17$-subgroup of $G$ is central

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups, sylow-theory

> Let $G$ be a group of order $935 = 5 \cdot 11 \cdot 17$. Show that the Sylow $17$-subgroup
> of $G$ is central.

**What I have:** The number of Sylow $17$-subgroups is $1+17k$, for some $k\in \mathbb{Z}$ and divides $55$. Thus, the number of Sylow $17$-subgroups is $1$. That is, there is just one Sylow $17$-subgroup and therefore is normal in $G$.

My problem is in saying that it is central, how could I do it?

If we consider the number of Sylow $11$-subgroups, we have that there are just one Sylow $11$-subgroup as well. In the case of the number of Sylow $5$-subgroups this is either $1$ or $11$.

It occurs to me that one way to show that the Sylow $17$-subgroup is central is to show that $G$ is abelian, but I don't know how to follow. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: $G$ need not be abelian, since there are nonabelian subgroups of order $55$ (because $5|(11-1)$). So $G$ could be of the form $K\times C_{17}$ with $K$ nonabelian of order $55$. The $17$-Sylow would still be central, but $G$ would not be abelian.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately for the line of attack in your final paragraph, not every group of order $935$ is abelian. We know that a group of order $pq$, with $p$ and $q$ prime, $p\lt q$, is necessarily abelian when $p\nmid q-1$; but if $p\mid q-1$, then there is a nonabelian subgroup of that order. That is the situation you have here, with $p=5$ and $q=11$. Thus, you could take a nonabelian group of order $55$, and then take the direct product with a group of order $17$. The result would be nonabelian of order $935$; of course, the $17$-Sylow would be central here, but the point is that the overall group would not be abelian.

Instead, consider how $G$ acts by conjugation on the $17$-Sylow subgroup $P$. We know $P$ must be cyclic of order $17$; its automorphism group has order $16$. So the action of $G$ by conjugation factors through $G/P$ (which has order $55$), and yields a morphism $G/P\to\mathrm{Aut}(P)$.

Must the morphism be trivial? And if so, what does that tell you about the action?

Comment: One can also analogously argue that any element of order $5$ or of order $11$ must centralize the (necessarily normal) $17$-group...

Comment: I think I understand a little Mr. Arturo. Does this relate to the normalizer-centralizer theorem?

Comment: @Hopmaths: Not really; you don't need it here.

Comment: You might want to have a look at the more general setting: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1073736/normal-subgroups-in-groups-of-odd-order